# Bash Centos7 "which" command

Tags: bash, shell, command, centos7, yum

I realize this might be a dumb question but I have a Centos-7 minimal server install and the "which" command does not exist or is missing.
I have a script that needs it and I cannot find out what the yum package is that installs it.
The code is below and is from a make file.

```
which grep > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

if test "$?" != "0"
then
    echo "\"grep\" command not found."
    echo "Installation is aborted."
    exit 1
fi
```

Any help would be appreciated... this is difficult if not impossible to google

Comment: Is `grep` or `which` missing?

Comment: As an aside, your code has several bugs. You want simply `if ! type -p grep >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo "grep not found, installation aborted" >&2; fi`

Comment: Very much not dumb; I was a bit surprised that `make` and `which` were missing from my centos7 experience, so thank you for asking. @Wintermute's answer was educational for me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To find a package in CentOS, use  `yum whatprovides`:

```
yum whatprovides *bin/which
```

In this particular case, the package is called `which`, so

```
yum install which
```

should pull it in.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `which`  command you can use `type` command.

```
type grep > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
if test "$?" != "0"
then
    echo "\"grep\" command not found."
    echo "Installation is aborted."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: This is the better solution.  `which` is nonportable, while `type` is mandated by POSIX and built into the shell.

Comment: And `type -P grep` output path to `grep`, exactly what `which` does.

Comment: The roundabout explicit examintion of `$?` is still unidiomatic and clumsy. The *purpose* of `if` and friends is to run a command and examine its exit status; you should almost never need to explicitly check if `$?` is non-zero. Anything which looks like `cmd; if [ $? -ne 0 ]` is better written `if ! cmd`

Comment: how do you get `type` to output _only_ the location of the command? I very commonly want to do `cat $(which ansible)` for example, to inspect python script contents.