# which command doesn't work on my computer

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

In the past, we 'which' command to get the info of the relevant software on our computer, Like:

```
which python
which git
```

But now it seems don't work on my MacOS Mojave. Is there anything wrong with my setting?

New edition:
The result will turn out to be like this

```
AA:~ AA$ which python
/usr/bin/which: illegal option -- -
usage: which [-as] program ...
```

New edition2:

```
AA:~ AA$ type --all which
which is aliased to `alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
which is /usr/bin/which

AA:~ AA$ type -all python
python is /Users/AA/anaconda3/bin/python
python is /Users/AA/anaconda/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
AA:~ AA$
```

Comment: "Don't work" is not a useful problem description. Is the command missing or does it produce incorrect output, or crash or hang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash Centos7 "which" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815420/bash-centos7-which-command)

Comment: I have added an example here when typing which python.

Comment: The `illegal option` message looks like maybe you have a wrapper of some sort. What does `type -all which` print? What does `type -all python` print?

Comment: I put it in the new edition2. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alias is what causes the error message. Apparently the alias definition is simply erroneous for your system. It's not clear what defined this alias or why; it seems wrong on several levels, so I doubt it's part of the standard install.

You can remove the alias with `unalias which`; but I'm guessing it's defined in one of your startup files, and should be removed from there - after this point, it should be gone for good the next time you log in.

But anyway, you should not be using `which` - it's better to accustom yourself to the POSIX standard command `type`. It was introduced specifically to replace `which` but it's apparently still hard to eradicate the old command from people's minds.

Comment: This looks like maybe you copied this alias definition from a CentOS box, which almost certainly has a different version of `which`. This sort of portability problem is exactly why you want to avoid `which` entirely. https://superuser.com/questions/1153563/what-does-alias-which-alias-do

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was when something from a `yarn global upgrade` replaced my system's `/usr/bin/which`.

```
/usr/bin/which -> ../local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/which
```

Since your error message is exactly the same as the text strings inside that program, it is possible that your issue is from a similar source.

```
console.error('which: illegal option -- ' + flag)
console.error('usage: which [-as] program ...')
```

"Fixed" with reinstalling `which` through the system's package manager (e.g. `sudo dnf reinstall which`). That may now interfere with whatever JavaScript package depended on that, but I plan on removing those globals, so I will not find out.

**Better fix:** I feel like my system is dirty now and needs all of its bin files checked... Comparing everything in `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin` to see if it has an equivalent in `/usr/bin` seems like an easy enough way to look for other points of interference.

```sh
for x in $(ls /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/*); do
    ls -l /usr/bin/"$(basename "${x}")"
done
```

Then those can be checked against the system's package manager with commands like the following. Then reinstalled if needed.

```
sudo dnf info ...
sudo dnf provides ...
```

---

More:

Seems weird to me that it would allow clobbering existing system programs. At the very least, I would expect it to have used `/usr/local/bin` instead. That extra system and system-like package management seems to be [why they have done away](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/821) with `yarn global` in yarn 2 (berry).

I have different packages for `sudo yarn global list` and `yarn global list`. Maybe using `sudo` at some point was my mistake?

---

P.S. Thanks goes to @[tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee), I was unaware of `type`. I have seen various other ways of attempting to handle different `which` programs and different versions of `which`, along with alternatives like `test` (and others I have forgotten), but `type` looks worth trying as a replacement.

P.P.S. Annoying to find out that this OS is configured to run tab completion through which.

P.P.P.S. Yes, I know scripting with the output `ls` is a bad habit.

Comment: `uuid`, `rc`, and `rtags` were the others besides `which` that overlapped with available (but not installed) system packages. Anything else was only a node_module and could be deleted from `/usr/bin`.